# Pass headers using ServiceStack's Swagger UI

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, servicestack, swagger

I am trying to add headers in our SS service using the APIMember attribute with ParameterType = "header".

Everything seems to be working except the header which is not getting added to the RequestContext. Hoping it supports headers. If it does, how and is there a way to not allow that header property in the Get query or path?

What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace Test
{
    [Api(Description = "MyTest")]
    [Route("/Test", Verbs="GET")]
    public class MyRequest
    {
        [ApiMember(
            Name = "SolutionName", 
            ParameterType = "query", 
            Description = "Test", 
            DataType = "string", 
            IsRequired = true)]
        public string SolutionName { get; set; }

        [ApiMember(
            Name = "Token", 
            ParameterType = "header", 
            DataType = "string", 
            IsRequired = true)]
        public string Token { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Help appreciated!

Thanks,
Nac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, looking [here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui#header-parameters) it appears that header parameters are not supported by default and you need to set `supportHeaderParams = true`. The NuGet install of ServiceStack.Api.Swagger has `supportHeaderParams = false`. You can change this variable in the index.html file that is located in the  `/swagger-ui` folder.